# Getting permission denied while creating a directory and how to add suffix to .exe to each files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a directory say source_dir and add few dummy files without content into this directory like file1.txt, file2.sh, etc

Now I want to create another directory say destination_dir and move all the files from source_dir to destination_dir but all the files that got moved from source_dir should be suffixed by .exe

Example:

source_dir

`file1.txt  file2.sh`

destination_dir should have output as

`file1.txt.exe  file2.sh.exe`

What I have tried :

1. I used `mkdir source_dir` -> But getting error cannot create directory. Permission denied.
2. `touch file1.txt file2.sh` -> I thought to use this command to create the files without content but not able to create a directory itself.
3. Once error is resolved and files are created in `source_dir` then I will use
   `mv .* source_dir destination_dir` -> To move all the files at once but for this command I am not sure whether this will work or not
4. Then how to suffix all the files with .exe is also challenging to me and got stuck.

Can someone help me resolving the error of create directory and how to add suffix to each files?

Comment: you are trying to create the directory in a directory where you don't have permission. Change to another dir.

Comment: Permission denied obviously means that your user doesn't have the permissions to write to that directory. Either modify the permissions to be able to write to that directory, use an user which has permissions to write to that directory, or use another directory where you have sufficient permissions to write to.

Comment: @mashuptwice I managed to create a directory and files using ```cd ~```

Comment: @mashuptwice But when I am looking for the files which I have created then not able to view them. I used ```cd source_dir``` then did ```ls *``` but this is giving me all the information instead of only the files which I have created in source_dir

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "all the information". `ls` will of course print all the files which are in the specified directory.

Comment: @mashuptwice when I am doing - ```cd source_dir``` I am in source_dir then I am doing ```ls``` then it is not giving me any result

Comment: @Vicky if `ls` doesn't produce any output, that is because the directory is empty. Obviously there need to be files in the directory in order for `ls` to find and show them. You can fill a directory with files through various ways, copying, moving, creating, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243352/discussion-between-vicky-and-mashuptwice).

Comment: I'd rather not continue that in chat. You are obviously missing basic knowledge about the directory structure and file operations in linux and I am not willing to walk you thru these basic steps. You might want to start by reading Chapter 3 of [Introduction to Linux](https://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/intro-linux.pdf) and afterwards come back to rephrase your question with the newly gained knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used mkdir source_dir -> But getting error cannot create directory. Permission denied.

It seems you do not have permission to create a fodler here. You might use `sudo mkdir source_dir`, but is likely a better idea to make the folder in a directory where you have write access EG. $HOME.

> Once error is resolved and files are created in source_dir then I will use mv .* source_dir destination_dir -> To move all the files at once but for this command I am not sure whether this will work or not

For moving use `mv .* destination_dir` from withing the source_dir. (IE, first `cd source_dir` then run the move command from above)

> Then how to suffix all the files with .exe is also challenging to me and got stuck.

You will have to loop over the files and move them one by one.

```
for i in * ; do mv "$i" "${i}.exe" ; done
```